# Iterating over maximum matchings

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, matching

A [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) is a set of pairwise vertex-disjoint edges, and it is maximum if it covers the largest possible number of vertices in the graph. There are efficient algorithms for finding such matchings, as well as implementations (see e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/maximum_matching.html) for an example in C++).

However, there can be several maximum matchings in an arbitrary graph; are there any implementations of algorithms that allow you to list all of them? I would prefer C++ implementations, but other languages are fine too.

Comment: A quite fast algorithm for the problem can be found here:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.108.4690

However, I do not know of any implementation of it...

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand the introduction correctly, the author is interested in *maximal* matchings, i.e. matchings that cannot be extended, whereas I'm interested in *maximum* matchings (which are also maximal, but the converse is not true).

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre have you found some algorithms / implementations to find all maximum matchings in some graph?

Comment: @bonanza: no luck so far.

Comment: Now I'm too looking for some implementations. I'm interested in bipartited graphs, though. Have you found any existing code?

Answer (score 2):

*"Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs"* -
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.107.8179&rep=rep1&type=pdf

*"Counting the Number of Matchings in Chordal and Chordal Bipartite
Graph Classes"* -
http://www.jaist.ac.jp/~okamotoy/PDF/matchchordal.pdf

I hope this can help you somehow.

Comment: Too bad the graphs are bipartite, but I'll look at who cites them, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem of finding all maximum matchings in general graphs is addressed by T. Uno (the same author as in the first reference given by Piotr, above) in this 2001 paper:

[A Fast Algorithm for Enumerating Non-Bipartite Maximal Matchings](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/enummat_nii.pdf)

Now maximum (cardinality) matchings are generally a strict subset of the maximal matchings, but once the *size* of a maximum matching is known, the maximal matchings are easily filtered to eliminate all but the maximum matchings.

However the time complexity of this "fast algorithm" proposed by T. Uno is dependent on the number of maximal matchings.  Indeed for a general graph G(V,E) with |V| vertices and |E| edges, the time complexity is O(|E|+|V|+Δ*N), where Δ is the maximum degree of vertices and N is the number of *maximal matchings*.

This would not be ideal when the ratio of maximal matchings to maximum matchings is high.  However the algorithm applies to general graphs, so it seems fairly reasonable to expect this sort of behavior in searching only for *maximum matchings*.